# Execute Anonymous dropdowns are greyed out in eclipse force.com plugin

Tags: apex, execute-anonymous

I have downloaded Java 7 32 bit and eclipse 32 bit Kepler Release onto windows 7 desktop.

I loaded the Force.com plugin and made a new apex project.  Tutorials work fine.

When I open the "Execute Anonymous" view to execute some anonymous code.  The "Active Project" dropdown is greyed out.  Restarting eclipse does not fix it.

What do I do so I can execute some anonymous apex code in Eclipse?

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008xEOIAY

The Execute Anonymous plugin sometimes gets confused.  So just force close the tab and re-open.

1. Press X next to "Execute Anonymous" view to close it.
2. Choose Window -> Show view -> Execute Anonymous
3. The Active Project dropdown is populated with the current project as well as other options are available.

Just needs a swift kick to wake it up.